# In Dialogflow, how many system entities can I use per Intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the free version for Dialogflow, I'm unable to get the test to use more than 2 system entities, I need to use 2 more, time and date, can you please tell me if this type of account has restrictions or can I use more 2 system entities per Intent? Thank you

Comment: You should be able to. Can you update your question to show a screen shot of the Intent in question and illustrate what you mean that you can't get it to use more than two system entities?

Answer (score 0):

An agent can have up to 250 entity types and maximum 30,000 entity entries. So in all of your intents if the total number is less than those limits that shouldn't be the issue. Here's the link for Agent limits from doc [Link to doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas)

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the quotas. Still, for some reason, the answers get triggered most of the time, but not all the time.Thank you for your help